# Stacked graph in with Grafana time series

Tags: mongodb, grafana

I want to visualize stacked time series in Grafana to see the total volume of multiple sensors (see picture below). I want to see a nice smooth line of the total of A,B and C. The time series are independent and the time stamps of A,B,C don't necessary align.

There is no stacking option in the new Time Series graph. Anyone knows how to solve this?

I am using Grafana (latest version) + MongoDB database + MongoDB plugin from https://github.com/JamesOsgood/mongodb-grafana

Your help is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Graph` panel. `Time Series` panel is still beta. But I wouldn't expect `a nice smooth line of the total of A,B and C`, because `the time stamps of A,B,C don't necessary align`.

Comment: Hi Jan, thank you for your help. I edited the question. As you can see the normal stacked graph also did not work. The main problem is that I want to sum time series with a different time stamp interval in mongo.

Comment: @Sandy_4242 Sorry, I rollback your question to original version. You have changed question context significantly. The proper procedure is to show appreciation (accept/upvote answer) and open new question. I told you a reason `the time stamps of A,B,C don't necessary align`, why your expectation `a nice smooth line of the total of A,B and C` is wrong. Newer version of the question needs IMHO mongodb skill and I never answer that kind of question.

Comment: No problem, from my perspective they were of course related as you can solve the stacking in Grafana or in the mongoDB query but I fully understand your point. Thanks again for the support. 

I read that more Grafana users are requesting the stacking option in the time series panel so hopefully they will add it soon.